# Probabilistic rooks problem

Tags: probability

Suppose k rooks are placed on a $x\times y$ board. What is the probability that none of the rooks attack each other?

---

My approach is as follows. Originally there are $ab$ rooms. Now when the first rook is placed it occupies $1$ room, so there are $ab-1$ rooms left. Now rooks can attack each other only if they are in same row or same column. So this rook can attack $(a-1)+(b-1)=a+b-2$ rooms. Thus the second rook can be placed in $ab-1-(a+b-2)=a+b+ab+1$ rooms. This has a probability of $(a+b+ab+1)/(ab-1)$ of happening. Now the second rook being placed, there are $ab-2$ rooms left for the third rook.

The second rook can also attack in $a+b-2$ rooms. So the third rook can be placed in $(ab-2) - 2(a+b-2)  = ab - 2a - 2b + 2$ ways. Probability of this happening  is $(ab - 2a - 2b + 2)/(ab-2)$. Similarly suppose that the $p$th rook is to be placed. $p-1$ rooks have already been placed, so $ab-(p-1)$ rooms have already been occupied, and $ab-(p-1)-(p-1)(a+b-2)$ rooms are available. Thus probability of placing the pth rook in valid order is $((ab-p+1) - (p-1) (a+b-2))(ab-p+1)$, that is, $1-(p-1)(a+b-2)/(ab-p+1)$.

Thus, the probability $\prod\limits_{p=1}^k(1-(p-1)(a+b-2)/(ab-p+1))$.

Comment: My approach is as follows.

Originally there are ab rooms. Now when the first rook is placed it occupies 1 room, so there are (ab-1) rooms left. Now rooks can attack each other only if they are in same row or same column. So this rook can attack (a-1)+(b-1) rooms= (a+b-2) rooms. Thus the second rook can be placed in {ab-1-(a+b-2)} rooms = (a+b+ab+1) rooms. This has a probability of (a+b+ab+1)/(ab-1) of happening. Now the second rook being placed, there are ab-2 rooms left for the third rook. Next in second comment.

Comment: To indicate your thoughts is excellent. Please add them to the main post.

Comment: The second rook can also attack in (a+b-2) rooms. So the third rook  can be placed in (ab-2) - 2(a+b-2) ways = ab - 2a - 2b + 2 ways. Probability of this happening= (ab - 2a - 2b + 2)/(ab-2).

Similarly suppose that the pth rook is to be placed. p-1 rooks have already been placed, so (ab-(p-1)) rooms have already been occupied, and (ab-(p-1))-(p-1)(a+b-2) rooms are available.

Thus probability of placing the pth rook in valid order= {(ab-p+1) - (p-1) (a+b-2)}(ab-p+1) = 1-(p-1)(a+b-2)/(ab-p+1). Next in next comment.

Comment: Thus, probability= product of 1-(p-1)(a+b-2)/(ab-p+1) where p is running from 1 to k

Comment: Did it for you. Next time, write directly in the post.

Answer (score 1):

We assume that rooks are placed on the squares, one rook to a square, with all choices equally likely.

We can assume that the rooks have labels $1$, $2$, $3$, and so on, and they are placed on the board in that order.  So they can be placed, in $(xy)(xy-1)(xy-2)\cdots (xy-k+1)$ equally likely ways.

To count the number of "favourables, note that Rook $1$ can be placed in $xy$ ways. For each such choice, Rook $2$ can be placed in $(x-1)(y-1)$ ways, for the row and column of Rook $1$ are now forbidden. Continue in this way, until we reach $(x-k+1)(y-k+1)$.

Comment: Please check if my answer is correct or not. It is in the comments of the main question.

Comment: The idea will work. It is very similar to what I used. The calculations are not quite right. For example, the number of choices of the second rook should be $ab-a-b+1$, there was a little sign error. Note that this is $(a-1)(b-1)$, exactly the $(x-1)(y-1)$ of my answer above. For the third rook you should have obtained $ab-2a-2b+4$.